# Can someone tell me how to remove or completely disable the playlist function altogether in Pot Player?

Tags: video, playlists

I only want to play one single video that I have selected to play from my listing in Download or other file location. I don't want to be presented with a list of other videos that I have watched in the past or have other videos start playing automatically when the selected video is finished. How do I prevent this from happening and just watch a single video and nothing else until I choose to watch another single video instead?
I'd appreciate any advice on this as it is very distracting and annoying having random videos that I may have watched months ago and no longer have any interest in pop up and start playing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

the playlist function can't be deactivated 100%, but we can change the way it behaves.

The settings in these screenshots should do the trick:

[Potplayer playlist settings](https://imgur.com/a/pz8yU1l)

These settings will do the following:

*Stop Potplayer from remembering recently played files in the "Default Playlist".

*Stop Potplayer from autoPLAYING the next file/s in the folder.

*Stop Potplayer from listing your recently played files next to your "Favourites"- list.

*Stop Potplayer from autoLOADING the previous + next file.

*Stop Potplayer from playing similar/same type of file in playfolder.

Hope this makes it work the way you wanted.

Best of luck :-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).